# Sencha Touch : How to change the default image of Select dropdown field?

Tags: javascript, css, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

[image]I want to change the default Image of Select Dropdown in Sencha Touch to a customized image? I have attached screenshot for reference. I am not able to find any property to change this image. More over I did not find any sencha class which I can override to replace this image.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: see this link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?174836-Custom-Form-Field-to-update-grid-cell-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 .x-field-select .x-component-outer::after {
        -webkit-mask-image:url('myImg')
    }
```